# Why does the TCPServer receive a string, though the TCPClient sends integers?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have written a TCPClient in Java that sends integers to a TCPServer. I included a sanity check just to cover the case that not integers are sent, but something else. If one sends integers, then one would expect that the other receivers integers.

However in the code following below, this does not seem to be the case:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

class TCPClient {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    int c = 0;
    while (c < 1000000) {
        System.out.println("Sent: " + c);
        outToServer.write(c);
        // Thread.sleep(1000);
        c++;

    }
    clientSocket.close();
    }
}



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

    String reg = "\\d+";
    int c = 0;
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));

    while (true) {
        String s = inFromClient.readLine();

        if (s.matches(reg) == false) {
        throw new Exception(s + "is an invalid input! Expected one String of digits.");
        }

        int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
        if (c + 1 != n) {
        throw new Exception("Expected: " + (c + 1) + ", but got: " + n);
        }
        System.out.println("Received: " + c);
        c++;

    }
    }
}
```

The string I receive are always 8 boxed question marks. Unfortunately I do not know how to describe them better. 
Now a few questions arise: Why do I receive this string? I would expect the program to run smoothly, with no exception, seeing only numbers. 
If possible, what is this string? What is it actually?
Third related question: How can I smoothly fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You use a  `java.io.DataOutputStream` to write the `int`s but you don't use a  `java.io.DataInputStream` to read them.

You indeed use a `java.io.BufferedReader` that is designed to read text from a character-input stream. That's why you receive data in a String representation.

Replace :

```
BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
```

by :

```
DataInputStream outToServer = new DataInputStream (connectionSocket.getInputStream());
```

and use the `DataInputStream#readInt()` method to read `int` values.